# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int okio.Segment.limit' on a null object reference in android

Tags: android, httprequest, okhttp

I am retrieving JSON data from the server in the background(AsyncTask)  and while creating an OkHttpClient builder is taking a lot of time(150sec Approx) to build and "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int okio.Segment.limit" is occuring . I don't know what exactly happening is. Can someone please help?

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
            String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
            String LoginURL = String.format(Locale.US, "%s/kioskLogin?iPadAppVersion=%d(%s)",Config.BASE_URL,versionCode,versionName);
            final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            JSONObject formBody = new JSONObject();
            try {
                formBody.put("emailId", emailID);
                formBody.put("password", passWord);
                formBody.put("deviceId",android_id);
                formBody.put("deviceName",deviceName);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, formBody.toString());
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();//Issue occurring line

            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(LoginURL)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("x-requested-with", "Mobile")
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "run: "  + e.getMessage());
                            showToast("Server not found :" + e.getMessage());
                           // dialogView.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        String result = response.body().string();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        UserResponse userResponse = gson.fromJson(result, UserResponse.class);
                        if (userResponse.message.equalsIgnoreCase("Logged-in successfully")) {
                            SharedPrefsUtil.setBooleanPreference(LoginScreen.this, "card", true);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LoginStatus", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("isLoginSuccess", true).apply();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor pref = getSharedPreferences("StoreSettings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            pref.putString("Storeid", userResponse.store);
                            pref.putString("Token", userResponse.token);
                            pref.putString("LicenseID", userResponse.licenseID);
                            pref.putString("LicenseKey", userResponse.licenseKey);
                            pref.putString("nodeId", userResponse.nodeId);
                            pref.putString("nodeNumber", String.valueOf(userResponse.nodeNumber));
                            for (EmployeeInfo employeeInfo:userResponse.employeePins) {
                                if (employeeInfo.kioskUser) {
                                    pref.putString("employeeID",employeeInfo.id);
                                }
                            }
                            pref.apply();

                            getStoreinfo();
                            getImage();
                            getCustomerVersion();
                            getStoreJson();
                        }
```

Comment: Are you using Firebase or showing an image on the notification?

Comment: @Marat   Yes using Firebase

Comment: Typically this occurs because if thread-unsafe use of an Okio Buffer, the data structure that powers the HTTP request and response body.

Comment: @JesseWilson Ok Any other way or Idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @Siva What about an image on the notification? What do you use Firebase for?

Comment: Full stacktrace?

Comment: 150 seconds or 150 milliseconds? It should never take 150 seconds, thats extremely bad. Something is very broken! Also note that you should create one OkHttpClient object and reuse it.